# Trying to access localhost mamp from iPad

Tags: macos, localhost, ipad, mamp

I want to visit my localhost that is being served by mamp on my iPad to do some testing. All the places I looked online say just to visit `ip:8888`.

This results in Safari showing a "server stopped responding" error. Am I  missing something? I have web sharing turned on as well, could that interfere?

Comment: Can you access the `localhost:8888` just fine from your Mac?

Comment: @slhck yep no problem, and I can even access the ip version from virtual box windows xp

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem from time to time.  I can workaround it by turning web sharing off, rebooting my Mac, and then turning web sharing back on.  Then I'm able to access my MAMP server from `ip:8888`.  It's not ideal but it works.